Does go trim out unreferenced packages when building a final binary, and if so, why do they still show in inspecting builds?
I had thought that go, at the linking stage, would remove unreferenced packages and functions (and any other such dependencies) that are unused. However, in trying it, I see references to those other transitive dependencies.
I created a simple file at go-import-tester:
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    sub "github.com/deitch/go-import-tester-sub"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, World!")
    fmt.Println(sub.Const)
}

It imports sub.Const from the other package. The sub package defines a Const, which the main imports, but also an exported Func(), which is not referenced by main. Func() calls to github.com/containerd/containerd, giving a nice large import to work with.
package sub

import (
    "log"

    "github.com/containerd/containerd"
)

// Const is a constant
const Const = "Hello, Sub World!"

func Func() {
    _, err := containerd.New("")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

}

Since my main never calls Func(), and therefore nothing from github.com/containerd/containerd, I would expect my final binary to have no dependency on github.com/containerd/containerd, let alone anything it depends upon.
Yet the build shows the following:
$ GOOS=linux go build -o importer .
$ go version -m importer
importer-linux: go1.21.5
        path    github.com/deitch/go-import-tester
        mod     github.com/deitch/go-import-tester      (devel)
        dep     github.com/containerd/containerd        v1.7.17 h1:KjNnn0+tAVQHAoaWRjmdak9WlvnFR/8rU1CHHy8Rm2A=
        dep     github.com/containerd/continuity        v0.4.2  h1:v3y/4Yz5jwnvqPKJJ+7Wf93fyWoCB3F5EclWG023MDM=
        dep     github.com/containerd/fifo      v1.1.0  h1:4I2mbh5stb1u6ycIABlBw9zgtlK8viPI9QkQNRQEEmY=
        dep     github.com/containerd/log       v0.1.0  h1:TCJt7ioM2cr/tfR8GPbGf9/VRAX8D2B4PjzCpfX540I=
        dep     github.com/containerd/ttrpc     v1.2.4  h1:eQCQK4h9dxDmpOb9QOOMh2NHTfzroH1IkmHiKZi05Oo=
        dep     github.com/containerd/typeurl/v2        v2.1.1  h1:3Q4Pt7i8nYwy2KmQWIw2+1hTvwTE/6w9FqcttATPO/4=
        dep     github.com/deitch/go-import-tester-sub  v0.0.0-20240528101732-393976ab1668h1:4zY+GLhj1BdrV0NmpyM1Rx+XTU82RiLEvQd45Wv1Z18=
        dep     github.com/docker/go-events     v0.0.0-20190806004212-e31b211e4f1c      h1:+pKlWGMw7gf6bQ+oDZB4KHQFypsfjYlq/C4rfL7D3g8=
        dep     github.com/felixge/httpsnoop    v1.0.3  h1:s/nj+GCswXYzN5v2DpNMuMQYe+0DDwt5WVCU6CWBdXk=
        dep     github.com/go-logr/logr v1.2.4  h1:g01GSCwiDw2xSZfjJ2/T9M+S6pFdcNtFYsp+Y43HYDQ=
        dep     github.com/go-logr/stdr v1.2.2  h1:hSWxHoqTgW2S2qGc0LTAI563KZ5YKYRhT3MFKZMbjag=
        dep     github.com/gogo/protobuf        v1.3.2  h1:Ov1cvc58UF3b5XjBnZv7+opcTcQFZebYjWzi34vdm4Q=
        dep     github.com/golang/protobuf      v1.5.4  h1:i7eJL8qZTpSEXOPTxNKhASYpMn+8e5Q6AdndVa1dWek=
        dep     github.com/google/go-cmp        v0.5.9  h1:O2Tfq5qg4qc4AmwVlvv0oLiVAGB7enBSJ2x2DqQFi38=
        dep     github.com/google/uuid  v1.3.1  h1:KjJaJ9iWZ3jOFZIf1Lqf4laDRCasjl0BCmnEGxkdLb4=
        dep     github.com/klauspost/compress   v1.16.0 h1:iULayQNOReoYUe+1qtKOqw9CwJv3aNQu8ivo7lw1HU4=
        dep     github.com/moby/locker  v1.0.1  h1:fOXqR41zeveg4fFODix+1Ch4mj/gT0NE1XJbp/epuBg=
        dep     github.com/moby/sys/mountinfo   v0.6.2  h1:BzJjoreD5BMFNmD9Rus6gdd1pLuecOFPt8wC+Vygl78=
        dep     github.com/moby/sys/signal      v0.7.0  h1:25RW3d5TnQEoKvRbEKUGay6DCQ46IxAVTT9CUMgmsSI=
        dep     github.com/moby/sys/user        v0.1.0  h1:WmZ93f5Ux6het5iituh9x2zAG7NFY9Aqi49jjE1PaQg=
        dep     github.com/opencontainers/go-digest     v1.0.0  h1:apOUWs51W5PlhuyGyz9FCeeBIOUDA/6nW8Oi/yOhh5U=
        dep     github.com/opencontainers/image-spec    v1.1.0  h1:8SG7/vwALn54lVB/0yZ/MMwhFrPYtpEHQb2IpWsCzug=
        dep     github.com/opencontainers/runtime-spec  v1.1.0  h1:HHUyrt9mwHUjtasSbXSMvs4cyFxh+Bll4AjJ9odEGpg=
        dep     github.com/opencontainers/selinux       v1.11.0 h1:+5Zbo97w3Lbmb3PeqQtpmTkMwsW5nRI3YaLpt7tQ7oU=
        dep     github.com/sirupsen/logrus      v1.9.3  h1:dueUQJ1C2q9oE3F7wvmSGAaVtTmUizReu6fjN8uqzbQ=
        dep     go.opentelemetry.io/contrib/instrumentation/net/http/otelhttp   v0.45.0 h1:x8Z78aZx8cOF0+Kkazoc7lwUNMGy0LrzEMxTm4BbTxg=
        dep     go.opentelemetry.io/otel        v1.19.0 h1:MuS/TNf4/j4IXsZuJegVzI1cwut7Qc00344rgH7p8bs=
        dep     go.opentelemetry.io/otel/metric v1.19.0 h1:aTzpGtV0ar9wlV4Sna9sdJyII5jTVJEvKETPiOKwvpE=
        dep     go.opentelemetry.io/otel/trace  v1.19.0 h1:DFVQmlVbfVeOuBRrwdtaehRrWiL1JoVs9CPIQ1Dzxpg=
        dep     golang.org/x/net        v0.23.0 h1:7EYJ93RZ9vYSZAIb2x3lnuvqO5zneoD6IvWjuhfxjTs=
        dep     golang.org/x/sync       v0.3.0  h1:ftCYgMx6zT/asHUrPw8BLLscYtGznsLAnjq5RH9P66E=
        dep     golang.org/x/sys        v0.18.0 h1:DBdB3niSjOA/O0blCZBqDefyWNYveAYMNF1Wum0DYQ4=
        dep     golang.org/x/text       v0.14.0 h1:ScX5w1eTa3QqT8oi6+ziP7dTV1S2+ALU0bI+0zXKWiQ=
        dep     google.golang.org/genproto      v0.0.0-20230822172742-b8732ec3820d      h1:VBu5YqKPv6XiJ199exd8Br+Aetz+o08F+PLMnwJQHAY=
        dep     google.golang.org/genproto/googleapis/rpc       v0.0.0-20230822172742-b8732ec3820d h1:uvYuEyMHKNt+lT4K3bN6fGswmK8qSvcreM3BwjDh+y4=
        dep     google.golang.org/grpc  v1.59.0 h1:Z5Iec2pjwb+LEOqzpB2MR12/eKFhDPhuqW91O+4bwUk=
        dep     google.golang.org/protobuf      v1.33.0 h1:uNO2rsAINq/JlFpSdYEKIZ0uKD/R9cpdv0T+yoGwGmI=
        build   -buildmode=exe
        build   -compiler=gc
        build   CGO_ENABLED=0
        build   GOARCH=arm64
        build   GOOS=linux
        build   vcs=git
        build   vcs.revision=7672895fecf99000f9401dc8c6780523b9a59870
        build   vcs.time=2024-05-28T10:18:01Z
        build   vcs.modified=false

And sizes:
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| importer-linux                                                                               |
+---------+---------------------------------------------------------------+--------+-----------+
| PERCENT | NAME                                                          | SIZE   | TYPE      |
+---------+---------------------------------------------------------------+--------+-----------+
| 13.80%  | .rodata                                                       | 2.4 MB | section   |
| 9.73%   | .gopclntab                                                    | 1.7 MB | section   |
| 9.55%   | .debug_info                                                   | 1.7 MB | section   |
| 6.64%   | .debug_loc                                                    | 1.2 MB | section   |
| 6.11%   | google.golang.org/protobuf                                    | 1.1 MB | vendor    |
| 4.64%   | .debug_line                                                   | 806 kB | section   |
| 4.54%   | .strtab                                                       | 789 kB | section   |
| 4.19%   | net                                                           | 728 kB | std       |
| 3.86%   | crypto                                                        | 670 kB | std       |
| 3.57%   | runtime                                                       | 621 kB | std       |
| 3.43%   | google.golang.org/grpc                                        | 595 kB | vendor    |
| 2.76%   | github.com/containerd/containerd                              | 479 kB | vendor    |
| 2.43%   | .text                                                         | 422 kB | section   |
| 1.85%   | github.com/gogo/protobuf                                      | 321 kB | vendor    |
| 1.77%   | .noptrdata                                                    | 308 kB | section   |
| 1.58%   | .debug_ranges                                                 | 275 kB | section   |
| 1.47%   | .symtab                                                       | 255 kB | section   |
| 1.22%   | .debug_frame                                                  | 212 kB | section   |
| 1.10%   | reflect                                                       | 190 kB | std       |
| 0.96%   | text/template                                                 | 166 kB | std       |
| 0.95%   | golang.org/x/net                                              | 165 kB | vendor    |
| 0.78%   | regexp                                                        | 135 kB | std       |
| 0.77%   |                                                               | 133 kB | generated |
| 0.71%   | math                                                          | 124 kB | std       |
| 0.71%   | go.opentelemetry.io/otel                                      | 124 kB | vendor    |
| 0.66%   | github.com/klauspost/compress                                 | 114 kB | vendor    |
| 0.63%   | time                                                          | 109 kB | std       |
| 0.60%   | encoding/json                                                 | 105 kB | std       |
| 0.59%   | .data                                                         | 102 kB | section   |
| 0.58%   | os                                                            | 100 kB | std       |
| 0.52%   | html                                                          | 90 kB  | std       |
| 0.41%   | fmt                                                           | 71 kB  | std       |
| 0.38%   | syscall                                                       | 66 kB  | std       |
| 0.36%   | internal/poll                                                 | 62 kB  | std       |
| 0.35%   | github.com/sirupsen/logrus                                    | 62 kB  | vendor    |
| 0.29%   | encoding/asn1                                                 | 51 kB  | std       |
| 0.27%   | strconv                                                       | 47 kB  | std       |
| 0.26%   | github.com/golang/protobuf                                    | 46 kB  | vendor    |
| 0.24%   | sync                                                          | 41 kB  | std       |
| 0.23%   | strings                                                       | 40 kB  | std       |
| 0.22%   | internal/abi                                                  | 38 kB  | std       |
| 0.21%   | mime                                                          | 37 kB  | std       |
| 0.19%   | vendor/golang.org/x/text/unicode/norm                         | 32 kB  | std       |
| 0.18%   | internal/reflectlite                                          | 32 kB  | std       |
| 0.18%   | github.com/google/go-cmp                                      | 30 kB  | vendor    |
| 0.15%   | unicode                                                       | 26 kB  | std       |
| 0.15%   | vendor/golang.org/x/net/dns/dnsmessage                        | 26 kB  | std       |
| 0.15%   | bytes                                                         | 26 kB  | std       |
| 0.14%   | context                                                       | 24 kB  | std       |
| 0.13%   | io                                                            | 23 kB  | std       |
| 0.13%   | vendor/golang.org/x/net/http2/hpack                           | 23 kB  | std       |
| 0.13%   | compress/flate                                                | 22 kB  | std       |
| 0.12%   | github.com/go-logr/logr                                       | 21 kB  | vendor    |
| 0.12%   | sort                                                          | 21 kB  | std       |
| 0.10%   | vendor/golang.org/x/crypto/cryptobyte                         | 18 kB  | std       |
| 0.10%   | bufio                                                         | 17 kB  | std       |
| 0.09%   | vendor/golang.org/x/net/idna                                  | 16 kB  | std       |
| 0.09%   | log                                                           | 16 kB  | std       |
| 0.09%   | go.opentelemetry.io/contrib/instrumentation/net/http/otelhttp | 15 kB  | vendor    |
| 0.07%   | internal/bisect                                               | 12 kB  | std       |
| 0.06%   | github.com/go-logr/stdr                                       | 9.9 kB | vendor    |
| 0.05%   | github.com/docker/go-events                                   | 9.5 kB | vendor    |
| 0.05%   | github.com/containerd/ttrpc                                   | 8.9 kB | vendor    |
| 0.05%   | text/tabwriter                                                | 8.9 kB | std       |
| 0.05%   | vendor/golang.org/x/net/http/httpproxy                        | 8.9 kB | std       |
| 0.05%   | google.golang.org/genproto                                    | 8.3 kB | vendor    |
| 0.04%   | .itablink                                                     | 7.5 kB | section   |
| 0.04%   | path                                                          | 7.3 kB | std       |
| 0.04%   | internal/godebug                                              | 6.6 kB | std       |
| 0.04%   | internal/fmtsort                                              | 6.6 kB | std       |
| 0.04%   | container/list                                                | 6.4 kB | std       |
| 0.04%   | vendor/golang.org/x/crypto/chacha20                           | 6.2 kB | std       |
| 0.03%   | encoding/base64                                               | 5.8 kB | std       |
| 0.03%   | github.com/containerd/typeurl/v2                              | 5.7 kB | vendor    |
| 0.03%   | compress/gzip                                                 | 5.1 kB | std       |
| 0.03%   | hash/crc32                                                    | 4.7 kB | std       |
| 0.03%   | github.com/google/uuid                                        | 4.5 kB | vendor    |
| 0.02%   | vendor/golang.org/x/crypto/chacha20poly1305                   | 4.0 kB | std       |
| 0.02%   | .go.buildinfo                                                 | 3.8 kB | section   |
| 0.02%   | internal/singleflight                                         | 3.7 kB | std       |
| 0.02%   | golang.org/x/sys                                              | 3.6 kB | vendor    |
| 0.02%   | internal/bytealg                                              | 3.1 kB | std       |
| 0.02%   | encoding/pem                                                  | 3.1 kB | std       |
| 0.02%   | errors                                                        | 2.9 kB | std       |
| 0.02%   | internal/cpu                                                  | 2.8 kB | std       |
| 0.01%   | vendor/golang.org/x/crypto/internal/poly1305                  | 2.5 kB | std       |
| 0.01%   | internal/intern                                               | 2.5 kB | std       |
| 0.01%   | vendor/golang.org/x/text/unicode/bidi                         | 2.3 kB | std       |
| 0.01%   | golang.org/x/text                                             | 2.1 kB | vendor    |
| 0.01%   | archive/tar                                                   | 2.0 kB | std       |
| 0.01%   | vendor/golang.org/x/crypto/hkdf                               | 1.9 kB | std       |
| 0.01%   | vendor/golang.org/x/net/http/httpguts                         | 1.8 kB | std       |
| 0.01%   | internal/testlog                                              | 1.7 kB | std       |
| 0.01%   | vendor/golang.org/x/text/secure/bidirule                      | 1.6 kB | std       |
| 0.01%   | internal/syscall/unix                                         | 1.5 kB | std       |
| 0.01%   | github.com/opencontainers/go-digest                           | 1.0 kB | vendor    |
| 0.01%   | github.com/containerd/log                                     | 984 B  | vendor    |
| 0.00%   | github.com/opencontainers/selinux                             | 760 B  | vendor    |
| 0.00%   | internal/itoa                                                 | 644 B  | std       |
| 0.00%   | hash/fnv                                                      | 360 B  | std       |
| 0.00%   | github.com/opencontainers/runtime-spec                        | 356 B  | vendor    |
| 0.00%   | github.com/opencontainers/image-spec                          | 356 B  | vendor    |
| 0.00%   | go/token                                                      | 324 B  | std       |
| 0.00%   | .debug_abbrev                                                 | 309 B  | section   |
| 0.00%   | main                                                          | 308 B  | main      |
| 0.00%   | github.com/moby/sys/user                                      | 308 B  | vendor    |
| 0.00%   | database/sql/driver                                           | 292 B  | std       |
| 0.00%   | .shstrtab                                                     | 263 B  | section   |
| 0.00%   | encoding/binary                                               | 244 B  | std       |
| 0.00%   | github.com/moby/sys/signal                                    | 196 B  | vendor    |
| 0.00%   | .note.go.buildid                                              | 100 B  | section   |
| 0.00%   | .debug_gdb_scripts                                            | 67 B   | section   |
| 0.00%   | github.com/containerd/fifo                                    | 0 B    | vendor    |
| 0.00%   | github.com/moby/sys/mountinfo                                 | 0 B    | vendor    |
| 0.00%   | github.com/deitch/go-import-tester-sub                        | 0 B    | vendor    |
| 0.00%   | github.com/felixge/httpsnoop                                  | 0 B    | vendor    |
| 0.00%   | golang.org/x/sync                                             | 0 B    | vendor    |
| 0.00%   | github.com/deitch/go-import-tester                            | 0 B    | vendor    |
| 0.00%   | github.com/moby/locker                                        | 0 B    | vendor    |
| 0.00%   | github.com/containerd/continuity                              | 0 B    | vendor    |
+---------+---------------------------------------------------------------+--------+-----------+
| 99.21%  | KNOWN                                                         | 17 MB  |           |
| 100%    | TOTAL                                                         | 17 MB  |           |
+---------+---------------------------------------------------------------+--------+-----------+%                                          

That is a lot of imported packages, which do add up to size, for something that isn't used.
It makes sense that at initial compile time, the go compiler would have to compile sub, which depends on containerd, so it would have to create the compiled static library for it. However, when linking, should it not be able to look and say, "you depend on Const but not Func, so I can get rid of everything else?
What am I misunderstanding?
EDIT:
I also compiled it with referencing sub.Func(), and the size of the binary does grow slightly, as do the sizes of the imported modules. E.g. containerd grows from 479KB to 516KB, github.com/google/go-cmp grows from 30KB, to 31KB, so clearly it matters. But why does it have them in there at all?

The linker strips unused stuff from you executable but formally there still is the dependency on that packages in your build.

True, but my analysis is of the final executable

The linker can probably prove that sub.Func is unreferenced and eliminate that.
But you import github.com/deitch/go-import-tester-sub which imports github.com/containerd/containerd which has an init function, which is expected to run. This can't be skipped, since other inits might depend on that package to be successfully initialized - and in the end the linker can't reason what side effects happen. Also, since the reflect package is picked up, all exported symbols are reachable.
For example if you have a module go-import with a main:
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    _ "go-import/pkg/sub1"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello from main")
}

pkg/sub1/sub1.go:
package sub1

import (
    _ "go-import/pkg/sub2"
)

and pkg/sub2/sub2.go:
package sub2

import "fmt"

func init() {
    fmt.Println("Init from sub2")
}

var World = Hello()

func Hello() *struct{} {
    fmt.Println("Hello from sub2")

    return nil
}

You'll expect go run to output:
Hello from sub2
Init from sub2
Hello from main

Event though you don't use anything from sub2 directly, the Go runtime does.

Hi @eik, thank you for the detailed comment. Are you saying that it is the init(), somewhere down the line, that does it? So if I imported sub2 but it had no init(), it would not show?

In my case sub2 without init() would be empty . Yeah, the linker should drop unused functions. But you might have a different understand what “unused” is than the compiler has. If you don't call a function it could still be part of a type. See also this thread in golang-nuts. when you don't want something not to be there, better not depend on it instead of hoping to let the linker do work your architecture should do.

Funny, I just had a convo with someone about this, and we said the exact opposite: to fix it, we need to break apart packages into separate ones, just so that unused things aren't referenced. It becomes almost one package per func! In other words, we are doing things manually that we want the linker to do!  I just did what you suggested, and when I do go mod why -m, I see both github.com/deitch/go-import-tester/initter and github.com/deitch/go-import-tester/no-init, i.e. the package I imported with _ github.com/deitch/go-import-tester/no-init but does nothing.

Checking the symbol table via readelf/objdump also shows a reference to noinit.

When you get “one package per function” when you break apart your program by usage, your codebase seems to have a problem with too little cohesion. That is probably beyond the scope of this question, but I don't believe a linker can solve your architectural problems. go mod why give you a explanation why you depend on something, which you do when you import it. When I depend on something I expect it to be reachable, at least via reflection. Otherwise I would try to eliminate the dependency, because compiling it but then throwing it away during linking is clearly wasteful.

I agree. Which is why I really don't want to do it. Yet if I care about binary size and dependencies, sometimes I just don't have a choice. In any case, is there a clear write-up somewhere that I can look at that says, "if you depend on a package but don't use any of it and no init(), linker will remove it, and you want see it in go mod why or objdump. If it has an init(), etc."?

AFAIK not. Firstly, You might depend on packages without calling code in it - for example to import a protocol buffer schema. Also, go mod why tells you why the compiler compiles something - not why the linker thinks it is needed.
If you care about dependencies might I suggest dependency inversion, dependency injection and hexagonal architecture? These are architectural answers to your problem, so that you don't have to depend on containerd when you don't need it.

Right, and the compiler compiles everything referenced; the linker pulls out just its required components. I am curious if any decent tooling examines go code (source or final binary) from a linker perspective, to report the dependency graph, why things would be pulled in, etc.?

I don't know any. You could try the source. Be aware that when reflection is used all exported methods are reachable, and when you pull in as much as you do something surely uses reflection.

Hi @eik, following up half a year later. I have been thinking about this. Does reflection used even once cause everything exported anywhere to be included, thus growing a binary significantly? I would guess it does, since it has no way of knowing upfront what would be reflected upon? Even something as simple as as json decoding/encoding depends upon reflect. What do you do when you actually care about binary size?

@deitch Don't depend on stuff that you don't use? As mentioned, depending on the linker to solve your architectural problems doesn't seem to be a good idea, in any language. And containerd is big, which is no surprise.

Yeah, that is quite true, it is large. It was just an example, though. I don't think it's unreasonable to expect that unused parts of packages would be trimmed out by the linker, and it is most of the time. The problem, as I understand it, is that if reflect is anywhere in the graph, even once, all trimming stops.

Not all, only exported types, and mostly when reflect.Value.MethodByName or reflect.Value.Method is used. go build -ldflags=-dumpdep should help to understand why something is included.

Oh, dumpdep, that is nice, thank you. I have a rather large binary that I would like to trim down, that may help.

Now I have to learn how to read the output. Hunting for the docs.
